# Device Orientation Controls using an object and not a camera in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am making my first steps playing with Three.js.

I am learning how to use the Device orientation controls. I found some demos in the Three.js site but only using the camera, I would like to see some example using an object.

Because I find that is not only about changing

```
controls = new THREE.DeviceOrientationControls( camera );
```

and put `controls = new THREE.DeviceOrientationControls( object );` that it works, because there are some parameters to change.

Do you have an idea about a demo using an object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the controls on a "phantom" camera, and then just copy the camera's rotation to the object or attach an object to the camera.

Comment: You mean to make a second camera? and then put the second camera looking at the object?

Comment: not looking at, 

literally after deviceControls.update() you go myNonCameraObject.rotation.copy( myCameraControlledByDeviceControls.rotation )

Comment: This is the problem, you have controls setting camera.rotation to something. You want those same controls to set .rotation on something other than a camera, but it doesnt work. Since both camera, and something (three.object3d, mesh etc.) extend from the same thing, they all have a position, rotation, scale etc properties. So, once you get those values on your camera, you just copy them to wherever you need them. You dont need to render anything through this camera.

Comment: Thank you very much @pailhead I made what you said and now I can see the rotation of my object changing when the rotation of my camera changes too. But now the problem with that is that my object doesnt have his initial position. If I open the site in my iphone I have to turn the Iphone to find my object, and if I open the site in my desktop I cant see the object.

Comment: is it possibly related to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35441349/three-js-device-orientation-controls-to-point-at-a-specific-target-on-load