# Three.js Device Orientation Controls to point at a specific target on load

Tags: three.js, device-orientation, google-cardboard

I'm using the Device Orientation Controls in Three.js to set up a web application for Google Cardboard. When I load the scene, the default target of the camera is the Y direction (Z on the phone) where there might not be any objects. I'd like to define a direction before loading. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to do this without the need to rotate the objects in the scene?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Did you come up with a satisfactory solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

Add your camera to a THREE.Object3D(). Rotate the parent object.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem as well, and the problem seemed to be due to my outdated JS files that I just copy&pasted from the zip file downloaded from https://vr.chromeexperiments.com.

Replace:

```
  <script src="js/third-party/threejs/three.js"></script>
  <script src="js/third-party/threejs/StereoEffect.js"></script>
  <script src="js/third-party/threejs/DeviceOrientationControls.js"></script>
  <script src="js/third-party/threejs/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```

with:

```
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/build/three.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script> 
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/examples/js/effects/StereoEffect.js"></script> 
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/examples/js/controls/DeviceOrientationControls.js"></script>
```

solved my problem.

Answer (score -1):

Use the lookat funcion

```
var vector = new THREE.Vector3( 1, 0, 0 );
camera.lookAt ( vector );
```